# Concatenating chars from a char array into one integer

Tags: c++, arrays, string, arduino, i2c

I've been trying to create serial motor controller from an ATtiny 85.  I have it setup as a slave.  It receives chars from a master one byte at a time and loads them into a char array for parsing.

The problem I'm having is I can't find a way to concatenate them instead of adding the values.

```
rxChrData = TinyWireS.receive();
rxString[rxIndex] = char(rxChrData);
rxIndex++;  
if (rxChrData == ':'){
          //rxString 2-3 each holds the value 9.
          //The lines below print "27" on the serial line.
          n = int(rxString[2]+rxString[3]+rxString[4]);
          Serial.println(n);
          rxIndex = 0;  
      }
```

The value of n is 27 and I need it to be 999.

I've tried converting it to a String, concatenate, then back to an integer. No luck. I've also tried a few other inept work arounds with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this

```
n = 100*rxString[2]+10*rxString[3]+rxString[4];
```

or maybe this

```
n = rxString[2]+10*rxString[3]+100*rxString[4];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option: use strtol():

```
#include <cstdlib>

n = strtol( rxString+2, NULL, 10 );
```

Answer (score 0):

for a more general approach...

```
if (rxChardata == ':') {
    // Consume the ':'
    rxCharData = TinyWireS.receive();
    int n = 0;
    while (isdigit(rxCharData)) {
        n = n * 10 + (rxCharData - '0');
        rcCharData = TinyWireS.receive();
    }
    Serial.println(n);
}
```

But you will need to check what happens when you call TinyWireS.receive() and there are no more digits... does it return '\0'? In which case the above will work.